# Horizontal scrolling for UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, scroll

I am creating a studying system that needs to swipe between N tables (ie 25 separate static tableviews each comprising of a question, options 1 - 4, an answer and an explanation). Does anyone know the best way to tackle this. Has anyone seen sample code which can help me out?

I understand that such a scroll behavior goes against best practices for UITableviews as this is reserved for deleting but we do not require deleting in our app and thus there is no conflict.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be able to slide easily between all the table views both forwards and backwards, use a UIScrollView with pagingEnabled set to YES.

Just set the width of the scroll view to the size of the app. Set the content size to be 25 times wider than that. Add each tableView next to each other inside the scroll view and UIKit should handle the scrolling and stopping at the right place for you.

However, if the user has to answer each question in turn, use a UINavigationController, loading the next UITableViewController when the previous question has been answered.

Comment: I am ok with the most part of it but pushing 25 viewcontrollers on a navigationcontroller might not be a wise choice

Comment: thanks Dean. I will give that a shot. I don't need the user input for this part. It is just for reflecting on their past answers and thus scrolling through the 25 questions.